# Recursion dilemma

Tags: c++, recursion

what's the difference between these two.

```
int find_set ( int v ) 
{
    if ( v == parent [ v ] )
        return v ;
    return parent [ v ] = find_set ( parent [ v ] ) ;
}
```

And:

```
int find_set ( int v ) 
{
    if ( v == parent [ v ] )
        return v ;
    parent [ v ] = find_set ( parent [ v ] ) ;
}
```

Comment: The second doesn't have a `return` statement if the `if` statement fails. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

The difference, as stated by @Omri, is that the second has no return if the if statement does not execute, leaving you with (hopefully) a compiler error for a code path with no return value. Unlike languages like Ruby, the last statement of a C++ method or function is not implicitly the return value.